# Lua script unable to detect/catch error while executing invalid linux command

Tags: linux, lua

I have the following function that works fine as long as I give it a valid command to execute. As soon as I give it a non-existent command, the script is interrupted with an error message.

```
#!/usr/bin/lua
function exec_com(com)
    local ok,res=pcall(function() return io.popen(com) end)
    if ok then
        local tmp=res:read('*a')
        res:close()
        return ok,tmp
    else
        return ok,res
    end
end
local st,val=exec_com('uptime')
print('Executed "uptime" with status:'..tostring(st)..' and value:'..val)
st,val=exec_com('zzzz')
print('Executed "zzzz" with status:'..tostring(st)..' and value:'..val)
```

When I run the script above I get the following output:

```
Executed "uptime" with status:true and value: 18:07:38 up 1 day, 23:00,  3 users,  load average: 0.37, 0.20, 0.20

sh: zzzz: command not found
Executed "zzzz" with status:true and value:
```

You can clearly see above that pcall() function still reported success when executing "zzzz" which is odd.

**Can someone help me devise a way to catch an exception when executing a non-existent or ill-formed Linux command using Lua script? Thanks.**

Edit: Restated my request after getting the clarification that pcall() works as expected, and the problem is due to popen() failing to throw an error.

Comment: You should rephrase and retitle your question since the the problem is that a Lua error is not being thrown, therefore there is nothing for `pcall` to catch. Your pcall code is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I use a method which is similar to your "temporary workaround" but which gives you more information:

```
local cmd = "uptime"
local f = io.popen(cmd .. " 2>&1 || echo ::ERROR::", "r")
local text = f:read "*a"

if text:find "::ERROR::" then
  -- something went wrong
  print("error: " .. text)
else
  -- all is fine!!
  print(text)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. I have modified it slightly to clean up the error message and get rid of newline created by echo. `print(text:match('^(.*)%s+::ERROR::'))`

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [`io.popen()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-io.popen), you'll see that it'll *always* return a file handle.

> Starts program prog in a separated process and **returns a file handle**
>   that you can use to read data from this program (if mode is `"r"`, the
>   default) or to write data to this program (if mode is `"w"`).

Since, a file handle returned is still a valid value for lua, the [`pcall()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-pcall), your local function inside the `pcall` is returning a true value (and an error is not being propagated); thereby, giving you a true status and no output.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have edited my question a bit, to make it clear that I am still looking for a solution to determining if my linux command failed to execute.

Answer (score 2):

I have come up with my own temporary workaround that pipes the error to `/dev/null` and determines the success/failure of executed command based on the text received from `io.popen():read('*a')` command.

Here is my new code:

```
#!/usr/bin/lua
function exec_com(com)
    local res=io.popen(com..' 2>/dev/null')
    local tmp=res:read('*a')
    res:close()
    if string.len(tmp)>0 then
        return true,tmp
    else
        return false,'Error executing command: '..com
    end
end
local st,val=exec_com('uptime')
print('Executed "uptime" with status:'..tostring(st)..' and value:'..val)
st,val=exec_com('cat /etc/shadow')
print('Executed "cat /etc/shadow" with status:'..tostring(st)..' and value:'..val)
```

And the corresponding output is now correct:

```
Executed "uptime" with status:true and value: 00:10:11 up 2 days,  5:02,  3 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.05, 0.19
Executed "cat /etc/shadow" with status:false and value:Error executing command: cat /etc/shadow
```

In my example above I am creating a "generic" error description. This is an intermediate fix and I am still interested in seeing alternative solutions that can return a more meaningful error message describing why the command failed to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than taking the time reading the whole file into a variable, why not just check if the file is empty with f:read(0)?

```
Local f = io.popen("NotExist")

if not f:read(0) Then
    for l in st:lines() do
        print(l)
    end
else
    error("Command Does Not Exist")
end
```

From the lua Manual:
*As a special case, io.read(0) works as a test for end of file: It returns an empty string if there is more to be read or nil otherwise.*